# What UI framework to use for Outlook add-in for web, iOS and Android?

Tags: ionic-framework, outlook-web-addins, html-framework-7, fluent-ui

I have been looking out for a UI framework that could support Outlook add-ins on the web, iOS and Android

Must-haves

- IE 11 support
- Way to show different UI in iOS and Android like Ionic framework

I have checked the following frameworks

- Framework 7 - Latest version doesn't support IE 11 :(
- Ionic 5 - doesn't support IE
- Fluent UI - Couldn't find any way to toggle the UI based on the device (iOS/Android)

It would be great if I could get a few recommendations for what framework is best suited for the above requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fluent UI for the purpose.

Please find more information here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/using-office-ui-fabric-react

Apart from that to learn more about Fluent UI you can visit : https://www.microsoft.com/design/fluent/

The same can be used to develop apps based on web, iOS and Android.

Comment: I did check out Fluent UI as mentioned in the question, but I couldn't find any documentation on how to modify the UI based on the device it is being used on(like Ionic).

We need this for building our add-in for Outlook mobile, which has strict guidelines for the UI/UX.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are trying to use Outlook Web on mobile browser?

Comment: no, I want to build the Outlook web-add-in which will work on Outlook Mobile as well
I was specifically referring to these guidelines https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-addin-design

Comment: Please follow our official documentation and see the existing Store Add-ins for reference.

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorial for building an add-in for both Desktop and Mobile as such

Comment: You can start with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator and to add Mobile support You need to add MobileFormFactor in Manifest. Follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-mobile-addins and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-mobile-support documentation for updating manifest for Mobile.

Comment: This I am aware, I was trying to understand if there is any UI framework, that works on IE 11 and can have different UI based on the device type, which event Fluent UI doesn't

Framework7 had this and it used to work in IE 11 and this is no longer the case

Comment: Fluent UI lib has a cross platform version(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/get-started/crossplatform). But this is still in the early stages of development, and currently only supports Windows and macOS components, with iOS and Android component support coming soon. This might be of use to you. Please keep an eye on updates to this Library.

Comment: As a follow up you can visit the open source page of fluentUI at https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui for more information.